# Change AIR applicationStorageDirectory on Windows

Tags: flash, air, storage, appdata

Is it possible to put several AIR applications under the same folder in C:\%username%\AppData\Roaming?

I know it uses id to create a folder for each app there to store data (applicationStorageDirectory), but that id doesn't allow spaces and I googled and couldn't find anything on how to add a subfolder to that path. There must be a way for publishers to keep all their apps under the same folder, or is this feature missing in AIR completely?

Comment: creating subfolders: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#createDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant have multiple applications sharing the same applicationStorageDirectory - the folder name is taken from the application id, and each app id should be unique.

If you want multiple apps to use the same folder, use File.documentsDirectory or File.userDirectory (or even File.desktopDirectory if you like).

Also, the text of your question suggests you have spaces in your app id. The recommended format for app id's is "reverse domain name" - this will mean the id never contains spaces (which is a good thing) and that you can be reasonably confident that no one else has released an app with the same id (again, a good thing).

Lets say your app is called "SuperApp" and you have a domain name "www.superdomain.com" - you would give your app an id of "com.superdomain.superapp"; thats the domain name in reverse (without the www) followed by the application name.

Comment: I didn't really want multiple apps use the same folder, just put all of the apps under publisher's folder there. Well, thank you for comprehensive answer.

Comment: You can specify the default folder to install to via the app descriptor file - but it will be c:/program files (x86)/.., not c:/%username%... see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fe1

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Was just wondering about the AppData files. Thanks again!